# Shorthand background CSS property failing in browsers

Tags: css

I have the following css/sass code:

```
lc{
  background-image: url(../img/header.png) ;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

I tried to use short hand and reduce to this:

```
background-image: url(/img/backgrounds/header.png) no-repeat center / cover;
```

But the shorthand is failing, not recognize by browsers(ex: Firefox)

Comment: Is there a tag like `<lc>`? Also, shorthand is `background` and not `background-image`.

Comment: Use `background` as short hand property.

Comment: Let's close this as typo. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `background-image` correct `background`:

```
 background: url(/img/backgrounds/header.png) no-repeat center / cover;
```

Comment: Let's not add answers. Let's close this as typo.